# ios hybrid app webview flash white

Tags: javascript, ios, css, webview

when I try to remove the node from bottom to top, it have flash white(see screenshot)~ but it work fine on Android.

And I have try use animate or transform to remove it, but it doesn't work~

have any idea?

ENV:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13G35

Code Example:

http://jsbin.com/bodiruniqe

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it but You can try to wrap the content in div:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```